# It's all about the journey

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, cipher, mazes

Are you able to find the hidden word?

> It's all about the journey, not the destination.
>   Come on! Find the route to exit.
>   Only key to understand all this, is the aged wise owner of the pitiless maze.
>   Perceive the right hints and you will value this a facile dare.
>   Seek and ye shall find.

[image: labyrinth]

### Hint 1:

> Beware the false paths! They're my insurance. They're there to avoid that someone can *skip* the steps and get straight to the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Along manshu's path, there are

> Non-white pixels, of the following colors:
>  `496d79 7a7661 767221 426769 6e6573 776670 724161 7a7767 6f6d64 2e4275 736371 676763 6d7a74 627163 667072 726761 7a7667 676762 2e4262 646b62 757366 2c6f69 616d67 677a72 6f7666 70726f 666565 72662e`
>
>  Using the obvious hex-to-ASCII conversion, we get `Imyzvavr!BgineswfprAazwgomd.Buscqggcmztbqcfprrgazvgggb.Bbdkbusf,oiamggzrovfprofeerf.`

It obviously isn't a coincidence it's a bunch of letters and punctuation, so perhaps we have a Vigenere now.

### Update

As Wu33o pointed out in comments, the key to the Vigenere is

> `MINOS`

Which gives the message

> Well done! Now free the Minotaur. **The key to unlock the door is out.** Only then, can you read the answer.

That "key" in hex, is

> 6f 75 74

The numbers manshu found are the colors

> 22: `6e7575` (`nuu`)
>  25: `6f7574` (`out`)
>  28: `6f7475` (`otu`)

So, using the relevant number

> and taking every 25th letter of the boxed text in the question, we get the word `theseus`.

Comment: The Vigenere key is "Minos", the owner of the labyrinth with the Minotaur

Comment: You're almost there! I thought it would have been harder... unfortunately, there still a last step that will give you a word pertaining to the context ;)

Comment: You did all the work, you deserve the rep. Take my edit :)

Comment: @ffao excellent teamwork ;) ...and just to assure that **all** this effort was needed, following one of the false paths would have ended up in finding another name that appears in the Myth. They correct key was mandatory

Answer (score 4):

Partial Solution:

Here is the path And some numbers

> [image]

So...we got some numbers there

> 25, 28, 22

Now "Seek and ye shall find." reminds me of

> Bible. So maybe the answer is related to a line in the Bible.